# There is already an object named 'Fabricantes' in the database when I want alter my table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework, alter-table

```
GO
CREATE TABLE Fabricantes(
    Codigo INT IDENTITY not null,
    Nombre NVARCHAR(100) not null,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Fabricantes primary key (Codigo)
);

GO
CREATE TABLE Articulos(
    Codigo INT IDENTITY not null,
    Nombre nvarchar(100) not null,
    Precio int not null,
    Cod_fabricante int not null,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Articulos primary key (Codigo),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Fabricantes foreign key (Cod_fabricante) references Fabricantes
);

GO
ALTER TABLE Fabricantes 
ADD Direction nvarchar(150); 

GO

--Create index indice on dbo.Articulos
```

Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 3
There is already an object named 'Fabricantes' in the database.

I'm new on SQL SERVER and I wanna alter my table and I can't and I don't know why

Comment: the message sounds like you are trying to run that entire script.  You only need to run the Alter Table statement.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of you already have a table with name of 'Fabricantes' in your database! So you can not create this table again!

Just press **Ctrl+Shift+R** keys to refresh the database and **right click** on your database and click on **refresh**.

You can just Alter that table and add your column or first drop the table and then create it again (If no data exists there!).

1. Just alter the table:

```
    ALTER TABLE Fabricantes 
    ADD Direction nvarchar(150) null;
```

2. Drop table and create it again (if there is no data in it):

```
    GO
    
    DROP TABLE Fabricantes;


    GO
    
    CREATE TABLE Fabricantes(
        Codigo INT IDENTITY not null,
        Nombre NVARCHAR(100) not null,
        Direction nvarchar(150) not null,
        CONSTRAINT PK_Fabricantes primary key (Codigo)
    );
    
    GO
```